# How to disable and enable a command button on click of another command button?

Tags: jsf-2

I have 2 command buttons as shown,

```
            <h:commandButton action="#{beanOne.getRefreshData}"
                    image="images/refresh_data.png" alt="#{messages.refresh}"
                    style="margin-top:8px" />

            <h:commandButton action="#{beanTwo.resetFilter}" id="resetFilterBtn"
                    disabled="#{beanOne.disabledBtn}"
                    image="images/reset-filter.png" alt="#{messages.reset_filter}"
                    style="margin-top:8px;margin-left:5px" />
```

where `refresh data functionality` which needs to be invoked in the `Application Logic Phase` is as such,

```
public String getRefreshData() throws Exception {
    try {
      LOG.debug("In class OneBean :  getRefreshData()");
      setDisabledBtn(true);

      // Some business logic code goes here


    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw e;
    }
    finally{

    }
    return IConstants.SUCCESS;
  }
```

[image]

The `RESET FILTER` button needs to be disabled as soon as user clicks on `REFRESH DATA` and after the `refresh data functionality` has been processed in the backing bean, only then it(`RESET FILTER`) needs to be enabled.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you want to disable it before the request is sent. Your current attempt only disables it after the response associated with the request is returned. This is indeed too late.

Throw some JavaScript into the game to achieve that.

```
<h:commandButton ... onclick="document.getElementById('form:resetFilterBtn').disabled=true" />

<h:commandButton id="resetFilterBtn" ... />
```

It will "automagically" be re-enabled when the page refreshes as response to the form submit request. In case you're actually using ajax, then make sure that the disabled button is covered by ajax update.

---

**Update**

As per comments, I just used this form and bean on a further blank project with most minimal configuration (and only one dummy image file).

```
<h:form id="form">
    <h:commandButton id="one" image="test.png" action="#{bean.sleep}"
        onclick="document.getElementById('form:other').disabled=true" />
    <h:commandButton id="other" image="test.png" action="#{bean.sleep}" />
</h:form>
```

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Bean {
    public void sleep() throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
}
```

To be sure, I also added this CSS to the test page because it was in Firefox not immediately visually visible if the button was disabled (although it was visible in the DOM inspector):

```
<style>input[disabled] { border: 5px solid red; }</style>
```

It also works properly.

Comment: Nothing happened as suggested. Even the button was not disabled even though the correct Javascript was there.

Comment: Are you familiar with JavaScript's `getElementById()`? It will only work if there's a HTML element with exact ID of `form:resetFilterBtn`. The exact ID cannot be derived based on the information provided so far, so I had to use an example value.

Comment: Yes, I am familiar. This appears in the generated HTML,        onclick="var cf = function(){document.getElementById('plateOverForm:resetFilterBtn').disabled=true};var oamSF = function(){if(typeof window.getScrolling!='undefined'){myfaces.oam.setHiddenInput('plateOverForm','autoScroll',getScrolling());}};return (cf.apply(this, [])==false)? false : oamSF.apply(this, []); "

Comment: Sorry, problem is not visible in information provided so far.

Comment: I cross check it with IE8. Any suggestions on why your approach works fine with IE and not with Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: It works for me in all browsers with Mojarra. I noticed that you're using MyFaces. I checked MyFaces-generated script once again and I think I see it. Try adding `return true;` to the onclick. Regardless, I'd be interested in knowing the exact MyFaces version.

Comment: Adding "return true" didn't help any further. Version is 2.0.23. Is there any way to achieve a solution.

Comment: No, there are no issues in JS console in Developer tools.

Comment: Works fine for me with MyFaces 2.0.23 on Tomcat 8.0.21 in Firefox 30 (and Chrome 40). So, sorry, problem is still not visible in information provided so far.

Comment: Would you please paste the code on how you build the whole problem.

Comment: The problem was indeed solved when first time you answered it.  NOT VISUALLY DISABLED. was disturbing from the beginning. It was this pain only,  Just as you said, "it was in Firefox not immediately visually visible if the button was disabled (although it was visible in the DOM inspector)" whereas it is visible in IE. Thank you a lot.

Comment: I already guessed :) You're welcome. By the way, consider using text+CSS instead of images for those buttons. It allows more styling freedom.

Comment: I got crafted a metal plate out of Brass  in your honour, which very soon will be couriered with along somethings as well.

Comment: Wow. Looking forward to it.

Comment: Sorry for this one. Due to my migration to a specific location for a job change at Accenture, I couldn't courier on time. I am going on 24th of this month to my hometown and the package will be delivered to your address. Really sorry for this one.

Comment: Hey Bauke, kindly have a look at my profile pic. It's updated with the brass metal plate showing your name. This one is for you. The golden ink hand written on the plate, especially for you.

Comment: Not sure what to say. This is truly an honor. Thank you, Shirgill.

Comment: You're most welcome. The package will reach your address within a 10 days time period.

Comment: Not yet. Perhaps it's stuck at customs for a while. Depends on the courier. I'll let you know once it's arrived.

Comment: BalusC: Ok, let me check with the courier service. And congratulations on reaching the 6 lakh mark.

Comment: It has arrived today :) It will definitely get a place at home. Thank you!

Comment: Great. You're most welcome. Is everything inside the packet(metallic plate, a pen, a kodak photograh & a tutor's cert.) in good state. A matter of concern to me.

Comment: How come ZEEF doesn't know the curator ‘bauke.schotlz’? That sounds silly. https://zeef.com/profile/bauke.schotlz

Comment: Because you typo'ed my last name :) The right URL is available behind the shortcut https://balusc.zeef.com

Comment: I didn't typed it. I went from the view (https://zeef.com/about) and clicked the link reflecting your name, and then tried to access your profile.

Comment: Aah, thank you for finding a typo mistake caused by my colleague. It'll be fixed in next release.

Comment: I thought ZEEF was smart enough to figure out the what a user is trying to access.